# react native eas local android build gradlew failure

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradlew, eas

Im running on a Mac M1 Sonoma.

I am attempting to do eas local builds.  I have successfully accomplished an ios local build with `eas build -p ios --local`.  All builds perfectly.  When doing a `eas build -p android --local`, I am getting an error when it runs gradlew.  I am manually making the steps now to track it down.  I run `npx expo-doctor` and it runs clean.  No errors.  I then do an `expo prebuild` and that finishes, no errors.  I cd into the android directory and run `gradlew` and I get the following error:

[image]

Any insight on this error?  Could this be a Java version issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my own solution.  Posting it here in case anyone else needs it.  When I first ran gradlew it gave me a notice that it could not find Java, and sent me over to java.com to install, which I did.  And I just installed the latest and greatest that was on their front web page, which was java 8.  That is what was failing.  When I did an EAS managed build, I looked in their logs and saw they were using JDK 11.  So I removed the Java 8, and then installed the JDK 11, and everything built as expected.